# Sample Second Moment of SDE

Tags: probability, numerical-methods, stochastic-calculus, expected-value, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a simple sde
$$\mathrm{d}X_t = \mu \mathrm{d}t + \sigma \mathrm{d}W_t.$$
Assuming $X_0 = x$,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X^2_t\right] = \left(x +\mu t\right)^2 + \sigma^2 t.$$
I have been seeking to approximate this curve by sampling the SDE.  I employ an Euler-Maruyama method to generate M discretized paths.  To estimate $\mathbb{E}\left[X^2_t\right]$, I fix a time point, then average the square value of each of the paths at the fixed time point.

The resulting curve does not agree with the analytical solution.  It is exponentially greater than the correct curve.

Is there something I'm missing about my method?  If, for example, I wanted to approximate the solution to a pde using Feynman-Kac, I would essentially do the same thing for $u(t,x) = \mathbb{E}\left[f\left(X_t\right)\middle|X_0 = x\right]$.  For a fixed $x$ in this case, I can recover the correct $u(t,x)$ using the exact same method.  This leads me to believe I should be able to do the same thing when $f(x) = x^2$.

Is there something strange about the second moment that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you try your method to estimate $\mathbb{E}[X]$? Just to make sure there is no coding error in simulation

Comment: Sounds like you have a programming issue somewhere.

Comment: Yes, the mean works absolutely fine with the same simulated paths.  I agree Ian, I've been searching for the coding error for quite some time.  I feel like I've been going crazy and that I have had a sudden lapse in probability knowledge.

Comment: Easy way to catch it: set $x = \mu = 0$ and let $\sigma = 1$ and see what happens. In a different scenario, try $x = \sigma =0$ and $\mu = 1$ -- you should see from there where the problemis

Comment: Yep, time to ramp it up ;)

Comment: Stupid question, I assume you are only squaring at the end, not during the dynamics?...

Comment: No, no squaring during the dynamics.  It was a simple matter of a missing $\sqrt(\Delta t)$ :/. Thanks @gt6989b, that was a simple test to find the bug.  Now on to the real problem with multiplicative noise.  Thank you again.

Comment: Oh, instead of $\sqrt{\Delta t}$ you had 1? That would do it, if the $\Delta t$ was pretty small...